# Best visualisation for user-rated skills

Tags: data-visualization, normalization

I have a mobile app for soccer games where user can rate each other and mention particular skills for each player. For example, after a match we ask each user to rate every other user and optionally select 1 or more "top skills" per user like

- shooting
- passing
- speed

What would be the best way to visualise these attributes historically per user?

If the user did not receive any top skill vote it doesn't mean he is not good at that skill, just that it doesn't particularly excel in it. Basically a lack of ratings shouldn't be treated as bad performance.

These skills are more useful to differentiate a player from others (e.g. a fast player vs a player who can shoot well). So we don't want to have a negative visualisation for lack of data.

Comment: What would it mean to you for a visualization to 'be the best'?

Comment: It would allow me to understand what a player is particularly good at: shooting or defending or speed